# Calling setstate on a parent component forces componentDidUpdate on its children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, parent component App and child component SearchBar, I want SearchBar to keep its own state, and after updating its state to call a function given by its parent as a prop that will update its parent state.

So on my SearchBar component I have

```
onSearchChange(event) {
        .
        .
        .
        this.setState({ searchTerm });

    }
```

And then

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.props.onSearchChange(this.state.searchTerm)
}
```

And on the parent component

```
onSearchChange(searchTerm){
    this.setState({searchTerm});
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">

            <div>
                <SearchBar onSearchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
            </div>
            .
            .
            .
        </div>
    );
}
```

But this causes an infinite loop where SearchBar's componentDidUpdate gets called which calls its parent onSearchChange to update the parent state but then SearchBar's componentDidUpdate its called again an so on.

If I use a callback in setState instead of componentDidUpdate to update its parent state it works correctly, but I just don't understand why SearchBar its updating if its prop its constant.

Comment: use setState callback method: `this.setState({ searchTerm }, () => this.props.onSearchChange(this.state.searchTerm));`.

Comment: That will work of course, but my question its why is componentDidUpdate getting called again if its prop doesn't change.

Comment: so many answers available for that ques, check the [stackoverflow results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=setstate+inside+componentdidupdate+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN785IN785&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifn-rQ1fjZAhUDRY8KHXxiAPQQrQIIMygEMAA&biw=1440&bih=803) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

componentDidUpdate provides two arguments prevProps and prevState, with it you can check if actual props or state has changed and then make changes to current state/props.. for example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
if(prevState.searchTerm !== this.state.searchTerm) {
   this.props.onSearchChange(this.state.searchTerm)
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, so componentDidUpdate its called when its parent state changes even if there are no actual changes on the props?

Comment: Yes, because componentDidUpdate is triggered by componentShouldUpdate, so if shouldUpdate returns value true comopnentDidUpdate is invoked, and componentShouldUpdate is invoked with default value true when component receives new props/state regardles if state/props was changed or not.

Comment: `prevProps` works really well too, if you want to compare previous props to current, in the case of updating a component if a prop has changed.