# Pushing dynamic state update in a child component to a parent component

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, timer, setstate

Context: I am building a timer app, and I have two components, App.js (parent) and Configuration.js (child).

I want to take a state in Configuration.js, which is initially set as `timerSecond: this.props.timerSecond` (being pulled from App.js through props) and update the same state in the parent component *as it is being updated* in the child component.

Here is a segment of my App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      timerMinute: 25,
      timerSecond: 0,
      isPlay: false
    }
```

And my Configuration.js:

```
class Configuration extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isSession: true,
            timerSecond: this.props.timerSecond,
            intervalId: 0
        };

        this.playTimer = this.playTimer.bind(this);
        this.decreaseTimer = this.decreaseTimer.bind(this);
    }

        // PLAY
        playTimer() {
            let intervalId = setInterval(this.decreaseTimer, 1000);
            this.props.onPlayStopTimer(true);
            this.setState({
                intervalId: intervalId
            })
        }

        // Decrease seconds
        decreaseTimer() {
            switch(this.state.timerSecond) {
                case 0:
                    if(this.props.timerMinute === 0) {
                        if(this.state.isSession) {
                            this.setState({
                                isSession: false
                            });
                            this.props.toggleInterval(this.state.isSession);
                        } else {
                            this.setState({
                                isSession: true
                            });
                            this.props.toggleInterval(this.state.isSession);
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.props.updateTimerMinute()
                        this.setState({
                            timerSecond: 59
                        })
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    this.setState((prevState) => {
                        return {
                            timerSecond: prevState.timerSecond - 1,
                        }
                    })
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Essentially- Every time seconds incrementally decrease from 59, the state timerSecond successfully changes in Configuration.js, but I'm not sure how to push that update to the parent level (App.js). I need it to dynamically update in App.js, because I have another component pulling from the same state (timerSecond) and displaying the timer tick on the page.

I've read about lifecycle methods like componentDidUpdate(), but I'm not sure how to use it in this context? Every time I try, I keep getting an infinite loop error message. I also came across this code

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
if(prevState.searchTerm !== this.state.searchTerm) {
   this.props.onSearchChange(this.state.searchTerm)
  }
}
```

on [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365944/calling-setstate-on-a-parent-component-forces-componentdidupdate-on-its-children), but I'm not sure this would help / apply to the dynamic aspect of my timer app?

Answer (score 0):

all you need, is to pass down a function from app.js to configuration.js

```
App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        breakLength: 5,
        sessionLength: 25,
        timerMinute: 25,
        timerSecond: 0,
        isPlay: false
    }
}
render() {
    const updateState = (newState) => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            newState
        })
    }

    return(
        <Configuration {...this.state} updateState={updateState}/>
    )
}
}
```

now updateState function is passed down as props to `Configuration.js`